# Jackson serialization of POJO to JSON missing ROOT element during serialization

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I have the below setup to enable Root element wrapping during serialization and deserialization of JSON. I am using Jackson library with Spring MVC Rest.
The Jackson library version I am using is 2.7.4.

But the below setup does not specify the ROOT element in the JSON object returned by my REST service. Am I missing something here, checked quite a number of posts and most have only the below config mentioned.

**pom.xml file as below**

```
      <jackson.version>2.7.4</jackson.version>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Building the Jackson object mapper object

```
private static MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter buildJSONMessageConverter() {

    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json();
    builder.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
    builder.serializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    builder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    builder.featuresToEnable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
    builder.indentOutput(true);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build());
    return converter;
}
```

**Class domain definition**

```
@JsonRootName(value = "Brand")
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility =     Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class Brand{
....
}
```

The JSON that is returned does not have Brand as the root node

Comment: Check rest of the code, it works as you expect it.

Comment: rest of the code works like a charm!